# Is there any way to use a database url with the mysqldump command?

Tags: mysql, url, command-line

Let's say I have a cloud hosting service that has a database. The way the hosting service's CLI provides the database connection info is a url in the typical form: `mysql://user:pass@hostname:port/db-name`. I want to give this info to the `mysqldump` command to pipe the contents of that database into other commands. But it appears that there is no option to do that, just options to provide the credentials separately. Google provides no help. Do I need to parse the URL first?

Comment: Why not write some tool to parse that DSN?